# How to add class or ID on chumper data table?

Tags: jquery, datatable, laravel-4

How can I add classes or ID on table using Chumper's Data table on Laravel 4 so I can add CSS and JS on it, I tried searching the net but none gives me a direct answer.

Here is my (working) code:

```
public function getSales()
{

  $sales = DB::table('tblsaleshistory')
  ->select('ordered_by',DB::raw('sum(salesTotal) as st, count(ordered_by) as sell'))
  ->groupBy('ordered_by');
  return Datatable::query($sales)
  ->addColumn('Name',function($model)
    {
      $html = $model->ordered_by;
      return $html;
    })
    ->addColumn('data',function($model)
    {
      $salesTotal = $model->st;
      return $salesTotal;
    })
    ->addColumn('%',function($model)
    {
      $percentage = "<span id='pa-".$model->ordered_by."'>".($model->st/5000)*100 ."</span>";
      return $percentage;
    })
     ->addColumn('sell',function($model)
    {
      $sell = $model->sell;
      return $sell;
    })
    ->searchColumns(array('ordered_by','sell','st'))
    ->orderColumns('st')
    ->make();
}
```

and in my view:

```
{{ HTML::script('js/dataTable/jquery.datatable.js') }}
<?php echo HTML::flash(); ?>
{{ Datatable::table()
->addColumn('PA','Total Sales','%','Sales Count')       // these are the column headings to be shown  
->setUrl('api/getSales')   // this is the route where data will be retrieved
->render();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there no other way, but to add class/id manually using Javascript, I have to wrap

```
{{ HTML::script('js/dataTable/jquery.datatable.js') }}
<?php echo HTML::flash(); ?>
{{ Datatable::table()
->addColumn('PA','Total Sales','%','Sales Count') 
->setUrl('api/getSales')  
->render();
}}
```

with a `<div id="salesdiv">` then on ready function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#salesdiv table").addClass("salesTable");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For single table try this:

```
Datatable::table()
->addColumn('PA','Total Sales','%','Sales Count')  
->setUrl('api/getSales')   // this is the route where data will be retrieved
->setClass('class1 class2 class3')
->render();
```

for id use `setId('test1')`

otherwise u can set in package config file (app/config/packages/chumper/config.php)

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Table class
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Class(es) added to the table
| Supported: string
|
*/

'class' => 'class1 class2',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Table ID
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| ID given to the table. Used for connecting the table and the Datatables
| jQuery plugin. If left empty a random ID will be generated.
| Supported: string
|
*/

'id' => 'test',
```

to publish the package config file u must run this artisan command on your terminal

```
php artisan config:publish chumper/datatable
```

I hope this will help